# Installed GitLab and now existing Git repos on same server are inaccesible

Tags: git, gitlab

I had a basic git server running for a while, and decided to install GitLab (on the same server) for the GUI, permission control, merge requests, etc. After installing GitLab, none of my repos from the original git server are accessible. I get the following error when trying to clone a repo or push to a repo...

```
git clone git@mygitserver.com:repositories/myrepo.git     Initialized empty Git repository in /home/myuser/myrepo/.git/
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: No s
```

And when I try what I found in other posts dealing with this issue, I get the following error...

```
ssh mygitserver git-receive-pack /home/git/repositories/myrepo.git
fatal: '/home/git/repositories/myrepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

How can I get my 'old' git repos into GitLab, or at least somewhere that they're still usable? GitLab itself runs just fine. I can setup repos, clone, push, and do whatever I want. It's great, I just need to be able to clone the existing repos so I can migrate them into GitLab.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md

Chris was right, this works perfectly.