# Use GitLab UI for plain git repos

Tags: git, gitlab

**The Objective:**
I have some existing `git` repositories and I want to view them in `GitLab`'s UI.

The easiest way would be to essentially copy, or [`import`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Import-existing-repositories-into-GitLab) bare `git` projects to `GitLab`. But I don't want the server to actually use `GitLab` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542689/installed-gitlab-and-now-existing-git-repos-on-same-server-are-inaccesible). I want to continue using `git` and not switch over to `GitLab`, just use `GitLab`'s UI.

Is there a way to use the `GitLab` UI to view plain `git` projects without copying and converting `git` to `GitLab`?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: You can still use git on the server, his problem was that gitlab-shell "takes over" the git user, so logging in over ssh as 'git' is problematic. I don't think there's any way to use GitLab purely as a repository viewer without just importing them.